# Should I use faced or unfaced insulation in a utility room area?

Tags: insulation

I'm trying to keep my unconditioned utility room from being so darn cold and hot during the year, and to keep the condensation line from freezing during the winter.

I figured insulating the area would be beneficial, but my county inspector made a remark during an unrelated project, a room renovation inspection, stating that faced insulation while up to code, is a bad idea because of the flammable cardboard backing.

If that's true, can I use my surplus room wrap I purchased in bulk for another project in the utility room?

Comment: If faced insulation is up to code then the backing is not a problem. Considering most homes use that type of insulation and don't catch fire, it's not a problem.

Comment: He may mean you have to put a fire resistant covering over the insulation, such as Type X drywall.

Comment: Typical building inspector. Those who can't do become inspectors.  (I know, it's a gross generalization).

Answer (score 2):

You could.

I would consider buying XPS foam and gluing it to the walls with foam board adhesive. It will let the wall breathe while insulating and not have exposed fiberglass or bare paper.

Good luck!